# ApplyFilter works until I hit the clear button which clears the filters

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a form which should filter by dates that users can type in. After typing the needed dates the user clicks the "limit"-button so that data can filter these range. It works really fine until the user hits the clear button.

The filtering STILL works BUT the validation weather the users has typed the dates ist NOT working. It throws the error "runtime error 3000. reserved error (-3201)
The validation is checking weather the date is typed in, if not, a message box should appears.

--This is the "limit button" that shows a range of dates--

```
Private Sub eingrenzen()

Dim strCriteria, task As String

'MsgBox if no entry    
' "Me.vonDatumFeld" is german and means "fromDate"    
' "Me.bisDatumFeld" means "untilDate"

Me.Refresh

If IsNull(Me.vonDatumFeld) Or IsNull(Me.bisDatumFeld) 

Then

    MsgBox "Grenzen sie bitte den Zeitraum 'von' und 'bis' ein", vbInformation, "Zeitraum eingrenzen"
    Me.vonDatumFeld.SetFocus        

Else

    strCriteria = "([Datum] >= #" & Format(Me.vonDatumFeld, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# And [Datum] <= #" & Format(Me.bisDatumFeld, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#)"
    task = "select * from TblTeile where (" & strCriteria & ") order by [Datum]"

    DoCmd.ApplyFilter task 'Wende ZeitraumFILTER an

End If

End Sub
```

--And this is the "clear button"--

```
Private Sub CmdLösch_Click()

Me.KIDText = vbNullString    
Me.FirmaTxt = vbNullString    
Me.DatumTxt = vbNullString    
Me.ProdArttxt = vbNullString    
Me.BeschrText = vbNullString    
Me.MaterialText = vbNullString    
Me.vonDatumFeld = vbNullString    
Me.bisDatumFeld = vbNullString    
Me.Filter = vbNullString 

Me.FilterOn = False        

Me.Requery 

End Sub
```

Comment: I've never used ApplyFilter but doesn't look like you are using it properly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.applyfilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *Filter* method:

```
strCriteria = "[Datum] >= #" & Format(Me.vonDatumFeld, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# And [Datum] <= #" & Format(Me.bisDatumFeld, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"
' task = "select * from TblTeile where (" & strCriteria & ") order by [Datum]"
Me.Filter = strCriteria
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: Then all your date values fulfill the criteria.

Comment: with this suggestion there is no error any more but now it limits the date range anymore. Therefore i tried

`strCriteria = "[TblTeile.Datum] >= #" & Format(Me.vonDatumFeld, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# And [TblTeile.Datum] <= #" & Format(Me.bisDatumFeld, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#" 

Me.Filter = strCriteria
Me.FilterOn = True `

This works, I getting the range of dates. But when i left the dates free it throws again the run time error 3000.

Comment: Yes, `Format` will fail for _Null_ values. So, if the textbox is empty, adjust the criteria to leave it out.

Comment: Hi Gustav, indeed there was an issue with Null values with the IF-statement. I changed it in
`If Len(Me.vonDatumFeld) = 0 Or Len(Me.bisDatumFeld) = 0 Then`
now it works. Thank you!